# tabu: adding struts before and after cell content

Tags: spacing, tabu, strut

I am using `tabu` package to easily typeset my tables. So, there are few problems that i have solved:

- vertical spacing (from cell content to borders) is less than line height and line depth, so i use `\strut`s before and after content;
- LaTeX does not break line at the beginning, so i use `\hspace{0pt}` at the very beginning of cell content to make LaTeX break line and add hyphenation;
- LaTeX does not hyphenate words with macro, so i have to add `\hspace{0pt}` between end of cell content and `\strut`.

Column spec looks like:

```
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|>{\strut\hspace{0pt}}X[0.4,L]<{\hspace{0pt}\strut}|%
                             >{\strut\hspace{0pt}}X[0.115,C]<{\hspace{0pt}\strut}|%
                             >{\strut\hspace{0pt}}X[0.115,C]<{\hspace{0pt}\strut}|%
                             >{\strut\hspace{0pt}}X[0.2,C]<{\hspace{0pt}\strut}|%
                             >{\strut\hspace{0pt}}X[0.17,C]<{\hspace{0pt}\strut}|}\hline
```

How can i declare a new column type (for example, Y) with these features using X type? Like this (but this does not work):

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\strut\hspace{0pt}}X<{\hspace{0pt}\strut}}
\tabucolumn Y
```

Comment: Add `\nolinebreak` before `\hspace{0pt}\strut` in the "end part" or you'll get an empty line in many occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of defining a new column type is not incorrect.  But I guess you miss the possibility of passing arguments to the `X` specifier.  This can be done as follows with a format requiring an argument:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\strut\hspace{0pt}}X[#1]<{\hspace{0pt}\strut}}
\tabucolumn Y

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth{Y{.5,C} Y{.5}}
  Text text and longer words with extra line&  Text text
  and longer words with indisputably elegant hyphenation algorithm\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```